# RPI fails to boot after reboot; ok after unplug

Tags: boot, power-supply, boot-issues, reboot, hifiberry

Four of my five Raspberry Pi boot flawlessly upon `sudo reboot`; one fails. This RPi, but none of the others, has a [Hifiberry Amp2](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-amp2/) mounted on the GPIO header.

I suspect for the below reasons that the failure to reboot is due to the Hifiberry Amp2 and the way this RPi is powered; although the Hifiberry manufacturer [does not think so](https://support.hifiberry.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8749806096541-Reboot-fails-cold-start-works).

1. To recover, I need to unplug the power supply from the mains, wait a bit then reconnect to power.
2. The RPi gets its power from the Hifiberry Amp2 (that is powered by an 18 V power supply), i.e., power flows in through the GPIO 5V pins which is the reverse of the usual direction.
3. The log of each failed reboot refers as last or second but last entry to the Hifiberry:

```
pi@knoutberry:~ $ uname -a
Linux knoutberry 5.4.79-v7+ #1373 SMP Mon Nov 23 13:22:33 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@knoutberry:~ $ sudo journalctl --boot=-1 --dmesg --lines=3
-- Journal begins at Tue 2022-11-29 23:45:56 UTC, ends at Mon 2023-02-27 06:52:45 UTC. --
Feb 26 17:50:14 knoutberry kernel: rc rc0: two consecutive events of type space
Feb 26 17:50:14 knoutberry kernel: snd-rpi-hifiberry-dacplus soc:sound: pcm512x-hifi <-> 3f203000.i2s mapping ok
Feb 26 17:50:14 knoutberry kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
```

On the other hand, HifiBerry Amp2 is a common device and surely not preventing reboots for everyone. And *snd-rpi-hifiberry-dacplus soc:sound: pcm512x-hifi <-> 3f203000.i2s mapping ok* is a normal status, neither an error nor a warning. BTW, the very last entry *Bad value for 'hidepid'* is also present in boots that work, i.e., after reconnecting to power, and [may be ignored](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16896).

Any idea how I could further investigate? Thanks for suggestions.